# Running jar with dropped file on bat

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I want to drag and drop a file on a .bat file. After I dropped it I want to run a jar file with the dropped file path as input. How can I accomplish to run the jar file with a relative path? The dir my .bat file is run is my user dir and not the dir where it is located.

```
goal: cmd /c java -jar myjar.jar -f %1
current: cmd /c java -jar c:\somewhere\myjar.jar -f %1
```

The point is, that the program(jar +bat) is part of a small automated deploy process and for every user there might be a different path to run the jar.

Comment: I understand that the myjar.jar is relative, but relative to what? To the drag&Drop batch or to the %1 path?

Comment: relative to the drag&Drop batch. The dropped file results in an absolute path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this works, it changed the current directory to the path of the batch-file

```
pushd "%~dp0"
cmd /c java -jar myjar.jar -f "%~1"
```

Comment: Is `POPD` implied at the end of the batch script or should it be issued explicitly to restore the directory stack state?

Comment: thanks, this worked perfect :) @Andriy when i start the script again it runs in the context of my user dir again

Comment: @Andriy M: POPD is for a normal path restore required or setlocal whould solve it too, but not the end of the batch

Comment: @mephi, @jeb: I see, it's simply not obligatory and in this case not needed. Thanks.