# How to open jar file by dropping files onto it

Tags: java, bash, file, batch-file

I want to get a file path, getting file by dropping it on .jar file.

Is it possible to do without batch intercept? Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350281/running-jar-with-dropped-file-on-bat) guy does it?

First question: Is it possible to open Jar file by dropping files onto it

Second question: If the first question is answered with "yes", can I get the dropped file's absolute path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible, as the windows explorer will not let you drag files on top of jar files to launch the jar. You will need to use a helper batch script, like this:

`@start java -jar applicationfilename.jar %1`

This works because when you drop a file on a batch file, windows just launches the batch file with the file's path as the second argument, %1 (%0 is the batch file's path).

Then, in the java application, you can access the parameters by utilizing the default String[] args in main:

```
public class DroppedFileAsArgumentDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("No file");
        } else {
            // Print the path of the file
            System.out.println(args[0]);
        }
        // To let you see the result before the window closes
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }

}
```

You will end up with a path like `C:\Users\saloalv\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DroppedFileAsArgumentDemo\dist\README.txt`
Empty spaces in the path will be preserved.

---

For fun I also made a JavaFX application that does the same job, but in a GUI. Here, you can see how you need to pass the arguments inside the application when using JavaFX.

```
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DroppedFileAsArgumentJavafxDemo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Launches javafx app using the arguments
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {
        Label filename = new Label();

        // Receive arguments from launch(args)
        List<String> arguments = getParameters().getRaw();

        if (arguments.isEmpty()) {
            filename.setText("No file");
        } else {
            // sets text to first argument, the file name
            filename.setText(arguments.get(0));
        }

        // Display filename
        Scene s = new Scene(filename);
        window.setScene(s);
        window.show();
    }

}
```

To not have a ugly black terminal, you need to launch it with javaw instead of java:
`@start javaw -jar DroppedFileAsArgumentJavafxDemo.jar %1`

Comment: Well... Thank you very much, exactly what I needed, thanks